# avoid the 'for' loop in matlab script by permuting

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

I have a code as follows:

```
Ne = 100;
H = rand(Ne,Ne);
g = zeros(Ne,1);

for e =1:Ne
    hue = H(:,e);
    ss1 =  bsxfun(@times, hue', hue) .* M;   % M is a Ne*Ne matrix
    g(e) = sum(ss1(:));
end
```

when Ne > 1000, it runs very slowly.

I read the matlab documents, and find permute function is a possible way to speed up.
But I tried a whole day and failed.

Here is my code, and I do not know what is wrong.

```
C = permute(bsxfun(@times, permute(H, [1 3 2]), permute(H', [1 3 2])), [1 3 2]);
g = sum(sum(C))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you do the math, you'll see that all you have to do is this:

```
g = sum(H) .^ 2;
```

Run speed: 0.000681 seconds, with Ne = 1000 (the original code took 3.047315 seconds).

**EDIT:**

Now, for your edited code, all you have to do is this:

```
g = diag(H.' * M * H);
```

Run speed: 0.072273 seconds, with Ne = 1000.

A speedup can be obtained if you notice that if you rearrange the terms, you can avoid a second matrix multiplication (which changes to a dot product) and all you have to do is sum the columns, like this:

```
g = sum(M.' * H .* H);
```

Run speed: 0.044190 seconds, with Ne = 1000.

It's always a good idea to do the math. We spend some time, but the code gains a good speedup. :)

*NOTE: Run speeds were measured by averaging the time of a hundred runs.*

Comment: thanks for your smart solution! Actually, there is another matrix M used in my code. I did not add it for simplicity. Now the code is edited and you can see the whole code.

Comment: I've edited my solution, I hope it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For your edited code, this would work -

```
H1 = permute(H,[1 3 2]);
H2 = permute(H,[3 1 2]);
p1 = bsxfun(@times,H2,H1);
p1 = bsxfun(@times,p1,M);
g = sum(reshape(p1,Ne*Ne,[]),1)';
```

There isn't a great performance improvement with this though, as it's a bit faster only on a limited range of small datasizes.